# TypeInitializationException was unhandled by usercode

Tags: c#, .net

I am getting the below error when I try to run my first MVC5 application which i am creating for learning purpose:

> InnerException : {"Could not load type
>   'Microsoft.Commerce.Flighting.Common.CatalogIdInfo' from assembly
>   'Microsoft.Commerce.Flighting.Common, Version=10.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=cde7056ef0bcb0fe'.":"Microsoft.Commerce.Flighting.Common.CatalogIdInfo"}

please bear with me even if there is little information provided as this is my first week in .net and MVC technology.

I have added all the required references. Do let me know for any other details.

Comment: Runtime wraps exception raised in static constructor inside a TypeInitializationException. The InnerException is the original cause of the problem. Check out the link for more information:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/10298278/1688718

Comment: yeah , I copied inner exception in this case.

Comment: Check the inner exception of the inner exception. Follow the inner exceptions all the way down untill there are no more.

Comment: Yeah that was the last of it after that inner Exception was null

Comment: Check the warnings in your build.  Many times you'll get errors whose root cause is something mentioned in the warnings.

Comment: Yes there is indeed a warning stating that reference to type Microsoft.Commerce.Flighting.Common.CatalogIdInfo could not be found from "C:\users\.................." but the main error says that this type was being pulled from Microsoft.Commerce.Flighting.Common assembly.